# How do I stop duplicates from being created in a Mongoose Array | NodeJS Mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, npm, mongoose, discord.js

Okay soo how do i stop duplicates from being created in a Mongoose Array

Heres My Code:

```js
 channel.send(`Welcome ${member.user.tag} Invited By ${invite.inviter.tag}`)
                client.invites[invite.code] = invite.uses

                const req = await InviteLogger.findOne({
                    ServerID: member.guild.id,
                    UserID: invite.inviter.id
                })

                if(!req) {
                    const doc = new InviteLogger({
                        ServerID: member.guild.id,
                        UserID: invite.inviter.id
                    });
                    await doc.save();
                };

                const doc = await InviteLogger.findOneAndUpdate({ServerID: member.guild.id, UserID: invite.inviter.id},{ $inc: { Joins: 1 } }, {new: true});

                if(req.Invited === member.user.id) {
                    return;
                }
                const doc1 = await InviteLogger.findOneAndUpdate({ServerID: member.guild.id, UserID: invite.inviter.id},{ $push: { Invited: member.user.id } }, {new: true});
```

Also Heres a Screenshot on how the Schema Looks:

[image: Schema]

Comment: You can use `$addToSet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `member.user.id` to be duplicated, use the following:

```
if(member.user.id.includes(req.Invited)) return;
```

This checks if `member.user.id` is one of the elements in the array.
And remove this part of your code:

```
if(req.Invited === member.user.id) {
    return;
}
```

This code does nothing as it checks if the entire array is equal to `member.user.id`, when all you want to do is check if it's part of the array.